# React app not loading always showing waiting for localhost

Tags: reactjs

Sorry for bad question but I am stuck here , when I `run npm start` , react app opens but it is always showing waiting for localhost , yesterday it was working, here is the code:

app.js

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react'
import logo from '../logo.png'


function Header() {
    return (
        <Header>
            <img src={logo} alt=''></img>
        </Header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: what does your terminal tells you ? or the console ?

Comment: @MaieonBrix it shows you can now view myproject in the browser.

Comment: And what happens when you go to localhost?

Comment: @yudhiesh It keeps on loading , waiting for localhost

Comment: Could you try restarting it?

Comment: @yudhiesh can you tell me the command as I started learning react yesterday

Comment: press ```ctrl+c``` in cmd to close the app and start it again by ```npm start```

Comment: `Ctrl-C` in the command line then run `npm start`.

Comment: @KetanRamteke same result not opening

Comment: try deleting ```node_modules``` and ```package_lock.json``` from the project directory, and install all dependencies again by typing ```npm install``` in cmd

Comment: @KetanRamteke done , still the same result

Comment: do the one thing, try using ```yarn``` package manager instead of ```npm``` and meanwhile, continue with your react learning on https://stackblitz.com or codesandbox.io

Comment: @KetanRamteke I created new project and that is opening